# Group by specified column in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, group-by

Maybe, this question is a little stupid, but I'm confused.

How to group records by specified column ? :)

```
Item.group(:category_id)
```

does't works...

It says:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" GROUP BY category_id

What kind of aggregate function should i use?

Please, could you provide a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to define, *how* to group values that share the same `category_id`. Concatenate them? Calculate a sum?

To create comma-separated lists of values your statement could look like this:

```
SELECT category_id
      ,string_agg(col1, ', ') AS col1_list
      ,string_agg(col2, ', ') AS col2_list
FROM   items
GROUP  BY category_id
```

You need Postgres 9.0 or later for [`string_agg(col1, ', ')`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).
In older versions you can substitute with `array_to_string(array_agg(col1), ', ')`. More aggregate functions [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).

To aggregate values in PostgreSQL is the clearly superior approach as opposed to aggregating values in the client. Postgres is *very fast* at this and it reduces (network) traffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`, `avg`, `count` or any other aggregate function. More on this topic you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217514/can-rails-active-record-handle-sql-aggregate-queries).

But it seems that you don't really need to use SQL grouping.

Try to fetch all records and then use [`Array#collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-collect) function to group `Item`s by `category_id`

Answer (score 1):

Grouping in SQL means that the server *groups* **one or more** records from the database table into **one** resulting row. So, if you for example group by `category_id`, you might have several records matching the given category, so you can't expect the database to return **all** columns from the table (that's what `SELECT *` actually does).

Instead, when you use `GROUP BY`, you can `SELECT` only:

- columns you have grouped by, and/or
- aggregate functions which are performed on all the records belonging to a resulting group

Depending on what you exactly need, modify your `.select` accordingly.