# Postgres: buckets always filled from left in crosstab query

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT mthreport.*
FROM crosstab
('SELECT 
to_char(ipstimestamp, ''mon DD HH24h'') As row_name, 
varid::text || log.varid || ''_'' || ips.objectname::text As bucket, 
COUNT(*)::integer As bucketvalue
FROM loggingdb_ips_boolean As log 
INNER JOIN IpsObjects As ips 
ON log.Varid=ips.ObjectId
WHERE ((log.varid = 37551) 
OR (log.varid = 27087) 
OR (log.varid = 50876)
OR (log.varid = 45096)
OR (log.varid = 54708)
OR (log.varid = 47475)
OR (log.varid = 54606)
OR (log.varid = 25528)
OR (log.varid = 54729))
GROUP BY to_char(ipstimestamp, ''yyyy MM DD HH24h''), row_name, objectid, bucket        
ORDER BY to_char(ipstimestamp, ''yyyy MM DD HH24h''), row_name, objectid, bucket' )

As mthreport(item_name text,  varid_37551 integer, 
            varid_27087  integer , 
            varid_50876  integer , 
            varid_45096  integer , 
            varid_54708  integer , 
            varid_47475  integer , 
            varid_54606  integer , 
            varid_25528  integer , 
            varid_54729  integer , 
            varid_29469 integer)
```

the query can be tested against a test table with this connection string: 
"host=bellariastrasse.com port=5432 dbname=IpsLogging user=guest password=guest"

The query is syntactically correct and runs fine. My problem is that it the COUNT(*) values are always filling the leftmost column. however, in many instances the left columns should have a zero, or a NULL, and only the 2nd (or n-th) column should be filled. My brain is melting and I cannot figure out what is wrong!

Comment: I'm trying to connect with psql and getting pg_hba.conf validation failures.

Comment: oops - sorry. I set up the guest account in a hurry and may have messed up something. I will check today what's wrong there.

Comment: The connect should be fixed now. Can you try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your problem is to use the `crosstab()` variant with **two parameters**.

The second parameter (another query string) produces the list of output columns, so that NULL values in the data query (the first parameter) are assigned correctly.

Check the [manual for the tablefunc extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html), and in particular [`crosstab(text, text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html#AEN144882):

> The main limitation of the single-parameter form of crosstab is that
>   it treats all values in a group alike, **inserting each value into the
>   first available column**. If you want the value columns to correspond to
>   specific categories of data, and some groups might not have data for
>   some of the categories, that doesn't work well. The two-parameter form
>   of crosstab handles this case by providing an **explicit list of the
>   categories corresponding to the output columns**.

Emphasis mine. I posted a couple of related answers recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777417/939860) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592419/939860) or [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110519/939860).

Comment: Thank you Erwin, kiss-de-hoand gnä'herr (='you da man', loosely translated)! I shall be trying the 2-parameter query and report back!

Comment: Bingo - I set up the second query per Erwin's instructions, and now things work like a charm! Next I will try using a function to provide the category fields. It would appear to me that the FUNCTION way is a nice workaround that enables the generation of "dynamic" crosstabs whose categories may not be known a priori. Am I right?

Comment: @aag: "Küss die Hand gnä' Frau!" would be the old-school Viennese greeting, but really only targeted at women - hand-kissing among same-sex people in the public wasn't en-vogue in the old Austrian empire. :D

Comment: @aag: About the dynamic function: this can only be done as long as the **return type is the same**. Else you'll have to return records with unknown columns - which brings you back to where you started.

Comment: I still have a lot of trouble trying to generate a function. The pivot should be on the calculated field **varid::text || log.varid || ''_'' || ips.objectname::text** FROM loggingdb_ips_boolean As log 
INNER JOIN IpsObjects As ips 
ON log.Varid=ips.ObjectId; but I really cannot figure out how to program a function that will pull out these values. Can you give me a hand?