# PostgreSQL crosstab query pulling columns from a helper query

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, dynamic-sql, crosstab

My Postgres crosstab query reads:

```
SELECT mthreport.*
FROM crosstab
('SELECT 
to_char(ipstimestamp, ''mon DD HH24h'') As row_name, 
varid::text || log.varid || ''_'' || ips.objectname::text As bucket, 
COUNT(*)::integer As bucketvalue
FROM loggingdb_ips_boolean As log 
INNER JOIN IpsObjects As ips 
ON log.Varid=ips.ObjectId
GROUP BY to_char(ipstimestamp, ''yyyy MM DD HH24h''), row_name, bucket 
ORDER BY to_char(ipstimestamp, ''yyyy MM DD HH24h''), row_name, bucket')
As mthreport(item_name text,
jan3 integer, feb4 integer, mar5 integer)
```

Is there any way that I can pull the three items enumerated in the last line (`jan3 integer` etc.) from an ancillary query? I tried to substitute the last line with `SELECT xyz FROM zyx`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

In the basic form of the query, you **have to** spell out the column names and types in the calling `SELECT`.

There are the [`crosstabN(text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html#AEN138247) variants that use a pre-defined return types.

For full automation you'll have to wrap each individual query into a function where you can predefine the return type. I posted a detailed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110519/939860).